# How to "push ahead" records with a given value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and MySQL. I have an `Article` model with a `user_id` attribute (this attribute represents the foreign key - `id` - for associated author users) and I would like to retrieve articles ordering those "for" a given author. That is, given I have following records:

```
<#Article id: 1, title: "Title 1", user_id: 1>
<#Article id: 2, title: "Title 2", user_id: 2>
<#Article id: 3, title: "Title 3", user_id: 1>
<#Article id: 4, title: "Title 4", user_id: 3>
<#Article id: 5, title: "Title 5", user_id: 1>
...
<#Article id: N, title: "Title N", user_id: M>
```

When I look for articles ordered "for" the author with `id` `1` (`user_id = 1`) then the returning articles should be ordered as-like the following:

```
<#Article id: 1, title: "Title 1", user_id: 1>
<#Article id: 3, title: "Title 3", user_id: 1>
<#Article id: 5, title: "Title 5", user_id: 1>
<#Article id: 2, title: "Title 2", user_id: 2>
<#Article id: 4, title: "Title 4", user_id: 3>
...
<#Article id: N, title: "Title N", user_id: M>
```

In other words, I am looking to retrieve *all* articles but making those *ordered* with this "priority": *articles created by the given author returned first and then all other articles* (that is, I would like to "push ahead" articles created by a given author).

How can I make that?

---

*Note*: I am looking for a Ruby on Rails implementation, maybe through the [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not that clear since you are searching for user_id 1 and a normal ordering by user_id would put those first anyway. I believe you mean to do something like:

```
SELECT id, title, user_id
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN user_id = @search_id THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, user_id
```

In your example above, `@search_id` should be 1.

Comment: The order by clause is "CASE WHEN user_id = @search_id THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, user_id" so you should be able to use that string and the parameter in your sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Article.where(user_id: 1).order("user_id ASC").order("id ASC")
```

Or this:

```
Article.where(user_id: 1).order("user_id ASC, id ASC")
```

Comment: The OP wants all the results, ordered by user_id,id. Your solution will only select articles posted by user_id => 1

Comment: I am looking to order articles "for" a given author, but also need to retrieve articles created by other authors. Your code retrieves *only* articles created by the given author.

Comment: I don't undestand what you want to do. What do you mean "for"?, everyone think you want to do a seach.

Comment: In other words, I am looking to retrieve *all* articles but making those ordered with a "priority" for a given author where the ordering "priority" is: first all articles created by the given author and then all other articles.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select 
*
from 
myTable
order by 
user_id, id
```

For a given user_id:

```
Select 
*
from 
myTable
where user_id='?'
order by 
user_id, id
```

Comment: How do you'd order articles "for" a *given* `user_id`?

Comment: Your last code retrieves *only* articles created by the given (one) author. I am looking to retrieve *all* articles but making those ordered with a priority "for" a given author. In other words, I would like to get first articles created by a given author and then all others.

Answer (score 0):

The query in Rails could be like this:

```
Article.order(Article.send(:sanitize_sql, ["IF(user_id = ?, 1, 2)", params[:user_id]]))
```

`IF(user_id = ?, 1, 2)` returns 1 or 2 for ordering articles. `sanitize_sql`, a private method, is used to sanitize parameters.

If params[:user_id] is always an integer, the query could be simplified to this:

```
Article.order("IF(user_id = #{params[:user_id].to_i}, 1, 2)")
```

Comment: How do you'd relate your answer with the question? *BTW*: Is the "simplified" query dangerous for SQL injections?

Comment: Yes, the simplified version is very dangerous.  You can never assume anything when you're dealing with user supplied data.  I would not offer that as a solution... the first one is better.

Comment: I don't think calling `to_i` against any string could result in any danger. Could you give an example?