# Is it possible to use question marks in 'order' methods-clauses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2 and I would like to know if there is a way to make the following:

```
@categories.order('user_id = ? DESC', params[:id])
@categories.order('user_id = ? DESC', @user.id)

# Note: It is almost the same as `@categories.where('user_id = ?', params[:id])`
# but for the `order` clause.
```

Above statements generates this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near '? DESC, ...
```

Comment: You can use ruby string interpolation and Activerecord::Base. sanitize_sql_array.

Comment: I never used the [sanitize_sql_array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array) method. Can you provide an example on how you'd use that in my case (with the `order` clause)?

Comment: `@categories.order ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['user_id = ?', @user.id])`

Comment: What is this SQL even doing? I've never seen someone want to order by an attribute where it is equal to something. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to change the order based on the `user_id`, returning those that match first, you should be using a `CASE` statement.

In raw SQL, it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY CASE user_id WHEN 34 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

That would bring all of rows where user_id is 34 to the top, leaving the rest to default ordering.

Now, like others have mentioned, `order` does not have any mechanism to sanitize SQL, so you will have to use the protected class method on `ActiveRecord::Base`.

It may look like this:

```
order_sql = Category.send :sanitize_sql_array, ["CASE user_id WHEN ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END", some_user_id]

@categories.order(order_sql)
```

Comment: What exactly does the `CASE user_id WHEN 34 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` statement? How could it "bring all of rows where `user_id` is `34` to the top, leaving the rest to default ordering"? I never heard of that... is it and should it be really used in cases like that explained in the question?

Comment: When you do an order statement, sql is using the value of the fields to do a sort.  So if you have `SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY user_id`, it is taking the value of `user_id` to apply the sort.  With the case statement, you are intercepting the value of `user_id` and returning 1 or 2 based on the condition.  Since 1 comes before 2, it gets placed at the top.

Comment: Also, you never explained what this is to be used for in your question.  I am only surmising your intent.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: OK (1 comes before 2), but I don't understand how it relates to placing at the "top" records with `user_id = 34`.

Comment: I read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800333) and I am "playing" around in order to achieve the same thing...

Comment: Because the case statement is returning 1 or 2.  If the user_id is 34 then it returns 1, if not, it returns 2.  It is returning 1 or 2 instead of the 34 or whatever the other user_id values are.

Comment: OK, but if it returns 1 then what does it mean / happen? And, what does it mean when returning 2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20882/discussion-between-sean-hill-and-backo)

Comment: I opened a [new related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804756) about using multiple `CASE ... WHEN` statements in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an `ORDER BY user_id = <some_integer>`. You can only order by a column ASC or DESC. There are some advanced cases that use the CASE keyword. Please read the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: The `ORDER BY user_id = <some_integer>` clause seems to work as expected: it "pushes ahead" retrieved records with `user_id = <some_integer>`. Why do you say I can't do that?

Comment: It's not actually working the way you think it is. I just ran `select * from clients ORDER BY id = 477` on my own db and it didn't order it any way other than the default mysql config order by clause. MySQL doesn't use order by that way. You can clearly see that if you read the documentation. What are you trying to do exactly? There might be another way to do it.

Comment: I read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800333) and I am "playing" around in order to achieve the same thing...

Comment: You're going to need a case statement then. And that answer is provided inside of the article you linked to. Have you even tried the answer provided in there?

Comment: Not yet (some reason for that is present in the comment to the @Sean Hill answer). I am not sure that case statement is a proper approach of accomplish that.

Comment: The answer @Sean Hill made, as well as the one in the article you linked to will do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Magicmarkker.  There is no other way to achieve it.  I didn't realize that there was another, identical question until I read these comments.  I would have voted to close instead of answer it.

Comment: @Sean Hill - I opened this question that explain a "specific" issue "inspired" by the other linked question. This and the other question are *not* identical (at least for me).

Comment: "I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2 and I would like to know if there is a way to make the following:" No you didn't, you opened the question to find an answer to your SQL error. You have received a few already. @Sean Hill's answer being the best.

Answer (score 0):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

If you look at the source, it doesn't look like it does anything with the question marks, as compared to the where clause source code. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Looking at GitHub too at the order method, nothing to do with the question marks:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L234

Answer (score -1):

You can encapsulate the where and the order method like this:

```
Model.where("user_id = ?", params[:id]).order("field_name DESC")
```

I think this should do it for you. I hope I understud it correctly.

Comment: No no, I don't need to "`SELECT user_id = <some integer>`". I need just to "`ORDER BY user_id = <some integer>`".