# What does it happen when using multiple CASE ... WHEN statements in the same SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802495), I have an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY 
  CASE user_id WHEN 34 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
  CASE status WHEN 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

As you can see in the above code, there are *two* `CASE ... WHEN` statements. What happens in this case? That is, *how records will be ordered? May those "doubled" statements conflict?*

---

**UPDATE**: I would like to make it to return records in this order: (1) records where `user_id = 34` and `status = 'active'`; (2) records where `status = 'active'` (without `user_id` conditions); (3) all other records. How can I make that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First will come all records where user_id =34 with "active" status, then records with user_id=34 and status not "active", then records where user_id not equal 34 and status equals "active" , finally all remaining records where status is not "active"

Comment: I would like to make it to return records in this order: (1) records where `user_id = 34` and `status = 'active'`; (2) records where `status = 'active'` (without `user_id` conditions); (3) all other records. How can I make that?

Comment: make it ` CASE status WHEN 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,   CASE user_id WHEN 34 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

Answer (score 1):

Order by are done in the order that you write them.

Your record will be ordered:

[first]
user_id = 34, status = 'active'
user_id = 34, status <> 'active'
user_id <> 34, status = 'active'
user_id <> 34, status <> 'active'
[last]